# Out of office service activation with an run on server agent

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Is there an documentation or an easy solution how i can activate the out of office service in an user mailfile with an external run on server agent?

I tried it like this, but it does not work...

```
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim dt As New NotesDateTime(Now)

    Set db = s.Getdatabase("SERVERNAME", "MAILFILE")

    Set doc = db.Createdocument()

    doc.AppointmentType= "2"
    doc.BookFreeTime = ""
    doc.CreatedByAgent = "1"
    doc.ExcludeFromView = "D"
    doc.Form = "Appointment"
    doc.From = s.Username
    doc.Principal = s.Username
    Call doc.Replaceitemvalue("$BusyName","")
    Call doc.Replaceitemvalue("$BusyPriority","")
    Call doc.Replaceitemvalue("$PublicAccess","1")
    doc.ApptUNID = doc.Universalid

    Call dt.Adjustday(-5)
    set doc.EndDate = dt
    set doc.EndDateTime = dt
    call dt.Adjustday(10)
    set doc.StartDate = dt
    set doc.STARTDATETIME = dt
    doc.Subject = "Out Of Office"
    Call doc.Replaceitemvalue("$UpdatedBy",s.Username)
    Call doc.save(True,False)


    Set doc = db.Getprofiledocument("OutOfOfficeProfile")
    Call dt.Adjustday(-5)
    Set doc.FirstDayOut = dt
    Call dt.Adjustday(10)
    Set doc.FirstDayBack = dt
    doc.CurrentStatus = "1"
    doc.GeneralSubject = "HE IS NOT AVAILABLE"

    Call doc.save(True,false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way how it works.

```
Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim dt As New NotesDateTime(Now)

    Set db = s.Getdatabase("SERVER", "MAILFILE")    

    Set doc = db.Getprofiledocument("OutOfOfficeProfile")
    Call dt.Adjustday(-5)
    Set doc.FirstDayOut = dt
    Set doc.StartTime = dt
    Call dt.Adjustday(10)
    Set doc.FirstDayBack = dt
    Set doc.EndTime = dt
    doc.CurrentStatus = "1"
    doc.GeneralSubject = "MESSAGE"

    doc.TaskState = "1"
    doc.CurrentSate = "1"
    doc.ShowHours = ""

    Call doc.Computewithform(false, false)

    Call doc.save(True,false)

    Call db.SetOption( DBOPT_OUTOFOFFICEENABLED, True)
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE (changed answer from Out of office agent activation to Out of office service activation):

Look in MailFile ScriptLibrary `OutOfOfficeLib` in Class `OutOfOfficeObj` for method `EnableService()`. There is the code you have to adapt and put in your agent.

With the code line

```
Call db.SetOption( DBOPT_OUTOFOFFICEENABLED, True)
```

you activate the Out of Office service. There are some other settings you probably have to do in addition. Just follow the called methods in `EnableService()` and figure out what is really necessary.

Here is a good description how to activate and how to deal with issues with [Out of Office service](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/01072009040728PMWEBSS8.htm). Changes in users Out of Office service status e.g. might be visible only after sending the user an email.

Comment: but i don't want to use the out of office agent...since domino 8 there is an out of office service

Comment: I am glad it worked. Thank you for sharing your working code for your specific use case. That is definitely useful for people looking for similar solution. The main point is `db.SetOption(...)` to activate the OOS. The field settings might depend on use case.