# VBA set out of office in lotus notes

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I've tried to set out of office in lotus notes 8.5 using vba in excel, unfortunatelly it does not work. I found the code in this discussion [Out of office service activation with an run on server agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184283/out-of-office-service-activation-with-an-run-on-server-agent/34263574#34263574) , I get the "OutOfOfficeProfile", but after I try to set the first day out, I get errors. I searched a lot of time but I could not find the solution of my problem.

The code I'm using is:

```
Private Function check(text)
    check = False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        logError text & ": " & Err.Number & ", " & Err.Description & " has occurred at " & Err.Source
        Err.clear
        check = True
    End If
End Function

Private Function create_mail_database_name(user_name)
    create_mail_database_name = Left$(user_name, 1) & Right$(user_name, (Len(user_name) - InStr(1, user_name, " "))) & ".nsf"
End Function

Private Function activate_out_of_office()
    check "activate_out_of_office start"
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim notes_session As Object: Set notes_session = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
Dim user_name As String: user_name = current_user_name
Dim mail_database_name As String: mail_database_name = create_mail_database_name(user_name)

Dim notes_database As Object: Set notes_database = notes_session.CurrentDatabase
check "after mail_database"

Dim profile_document As Object: Set profile_document = notes_database.GetProfileDocument("OutOfOfficeProfile")
check "after profile document"

profile_document.FirstDayOut = "17.12.2015"
check "after profile_document.firstdayout"
profile_document.StartTime = "00:00:00"
check "after start time"

profile_document.FirstDayBack = "27.12.2015"
check "after first day back"
profile_document.EndTime = "00:00:00"
check "after end time "

profile_document.CurrentStatus = "1"
check "after current status"

profile_document.GeneralSubject = "HE IS NOT AVAILABLE"
profile_document.GeneralMessage = "general message"
check "after general subject"

Call profile_document.computeWithForm(False, False)
Call profile_document.Save(True, False)
check "after save"

Dim DBOPT_OUTOFOFFICEENABLED As Integer: DBOPT_OUTOFOFFICEENABLED = 74
Call notes_database.SetOption(74, True)
check "after activate"

    check "activate_out_of_office end"
End Function
```

The failure I get are:

- after profile document: 438, Objekt unterstützt diese Eigenschaft oder Methode nicht has occurred at VBAProject
- after profile_document.firstdayout: 91, Objektvariable oder With-Blockvariable nicht festgelegt has occurred at VBAProject
- activate_out_of_office_end_normal_58981,79: 91, Objektvariable oder With-Blockvariable nicht festgelegt has occurred at VBAProject

Comment: "I get errors" is not a sufficient error description. Post the code you use (not just a link to the code you started with) and post the EXACT error. Then post what you already tried. After that probably someone can help you... The only answer you could get is "but the code works for me"... Very helpful, isn't it?

Comment: FirstDayOut, StartTime, FirstDayBack, EndTime, dateFirstDayOut, dateFirstDayBack are all date values, do not use a string. Use a tool like [NotesPeek](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24005686) to have a look how the notes generated profile looks like.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST: The posted code is NOT complete. Functions `current_user_name` and `create_mail_database_name` are missing.

SECOND: The servername for getting user mailfile in the most cases is NOT empty, you need to fill it somehow.

THIRD: These two will cause `mail_database` to be a "random database on your local computer" (at best, might already cause an error).

Without having the "right" database, the `mail_database.Getprofiledocument("OutOfOfficeProfile")` will fail and therefor trying to read a property of that document will result in something invalid.

Try to replace `Dim mail_database As Object: Set mail_database = notes_session.Getdatabase("", mail_database_name)` with these two lines and it will work:

```
Dim mail_database As Object
Set mail_database = notes_session.Getdatabase("", "")
Call mail_database.OpenMail()
```

But as you do not want to use the proper function for this, lets go for the other "Dos" and "Donts": Having a code that sais `On Error Resume Next` really is worst practice: You need to CATCH the error and stop execution. 
Replace this line with `On Error goto ErrorHandler` and add the following lines of code at the end of your code:

```
  Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & " in line " & Erl
```

That way you catch the FIRST error that occurs and don't try to continue although it is impossible.

Now you can debug your code.

IF your code really returns the users mailfile (which is possible, but depends on some luck), the first error you will find will be at `Set profile_document.FirstDayOut = leaving_date`

As FirstDayOut is NOT an Object, but a simple array you should not use Set here: `profile_document.FirstDayOut = leaving_date` is totally sufficient.

Now continue debugging, and you will probably get working code...

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work. I've updated my code above. The function current_user_name returns a string with the first and second name, e.g. "Christioph Wolf".

Comment: The use of my code before seems to work, with other functions I can send e-mails (Dim mail_database As Object: Set mail_database = notes_session.Getdatabase("", mail_database_name) ). The code for mail_database_name you can find on the top.

Comment: ok... Could you PLEASE use an appropriate error handler and do not use `On Error Resume Next` as this makes finding errors almost impossible...

Comment: So, I've change the code, the start and end date are strings like "22.12.2015". The out of office profile gets all new data, but it's not activated. I have no idea why, I don't get any error. I've added the code "Call mail_database.SetOption( DBOPT_OUTOFOFFICEENABLED, True)" at the end where DBOPT_OUTOFOFFICEENABLED = 74, but it's not activated.

Comment: Do you use OutOfOfficeService (OOS) or OutOfOfficeAgent (OOA)? If you don't know -> Go ask your Administrator. The code is for OOS and will not work for OOA.